# for loop in vb.net add a counter to existing string

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop which goes like this:

```
for i = 0 as integer to 100
    result &= "Name" & sqldr("name")
    result &= "Lastname" & sqldr("lastname")
    result &= "dob" & sqldr("dob")
next
```

The sqldr is the sql datareader (not important here)
I want my end result to be:

```
Name1 = Sam
Lastname1 = Davis
dob1 = 01/01/1966

Name2 = 
...
Name3 =
```

and so on depending on how many records are in the database. 
How do I make this happen in this for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you should be using a StringBuilder as it is more efficient than concatenating strings.

So the following should yield the expected result (sorry I am or aquainted to C#):

```
Dim sb as StringBuilder = new StringBuilder() ' that is where I am not so sure

for i = 0 as integer to 100
    sb.AppendFormat("Name{0} = {1}", i, sqldr("name")
    sb.AppendFormat("Lastname{0} = {1}", i, sqldr("lastname")
    sb.AppendFormat("dob{0} = {1}", i, sqldr("dob")
next

result = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: I agree that the StringBuilder is a way better way for him to do this, however he said that it needs to loop through the number of records found.  So this means he needs to return a count from his select statement.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
for i = 0 as integer to 100
    result &= "ApplicantName" & i.ToString() & " = " & sqldr("name")
    result &= "Lastname" & i.ToString() & " = " sqldr("lastname")
    result &= "dob" & i.ToString() & " = " sqldr("dob") & "\n\n"
next
```

But, for better performance, you should be using [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) and [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx):

```
Dim sb as StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
for i = 0 as Integer to 100
    sb.Append(String.Format("ApplicantName{0} = {1}", i, sqldr("name"))
    sb.Append(String.Format("Lastname{0} = {1}", i, sqldr("lastname"))
    sb.Append(String.Format("dob{0} = {1}\n\n", i, sqldr("dob"))
next
Dim result as String = sb.ToString()
```

StringBuilder also has an [AppendFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdekwk0b.aspx) overload, that makes this even easier:

```
Dim sb as StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
for i = 0 as Integer to 100
    sb.AppendFormat("ApplicantName{0} = {1}", i, sqldr("name")
    sb.AppendFormat("Lastname{0} = {1}", i, sqldr("lastname")
    sb.AppendFormat("dob{0} = {1}\n\n", i, sqldr("dob")
next
Dim result as String = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: String concatenation is not very efficient when dealing with larger numbers, use StringBuilder instead.

Comment: @Obalix - I am well aware of that. I was editing when you added your comment ;)

Comment: slight correction to the existing question -
the result should have "Applicant" prefix on to it
Applicant1Name = "sam
...
Applicant2Name = ...

Comment: @wedds - For real? You can't figure out the change from "Name" to "ApplicantName" by yourself?

Comment: be nice guys, im not as smart as u guys

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to do a select before your For loop.  The select will get the total number of records returned.  Store that number in a variable.

```
Dim sqlcount as integer = 100 'this should actually be the result of your sql query
for i = 0 as integer to sqlcount
    result &= "Name" & sqldr("name")
    result &= "Lastname" & sqldr("lastname")
    result &= "dob" & sqldr("dob")
    i = i + 1
next
```

Comment: and yes, as stated above, you should use String.Format and StringBuilder for better performance.