# Check if first 3 items in listview1 matches one of listview2's items

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a project where the program gets items from a table and puts it in a listview. Now I want to check if the top 3 items matches the items in another listview i have set up and return a message whether or not listview1 contains any items from listview2. I can do this for the whole listview1 but I want to check the top 3 only.

```
For Each li As ListViewItem In ListView2.Items
    Dim liToFind As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(li.Text)
    If Not IsNothing(liToFind) Then
       Using New Centered_MessageBox(Me)
           MessageBox.Show(li.Text & " has released a new episode!", "New release", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
       End Using
    End If
Next
```

This is the code for what I have so far, im checking the text of the items in listview2 to see if it matches any of the items in listview1, can't figure out how to do it with the top 3 only though.

Help would be greatly apriciated!

Comment: use a counter and exit the loop when the counter is reached.
Here is asimilar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315331/for-loop-in-vb-net-add-a-counter-to-existing-string

Comment: Can you give me an example? :D im rather stupid </3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example - obviously you can be cleverer here .

```
Dim checkrows As Integer = 3
Dim numFound As Integer
    For row As Integer = 0 To Math.Min(checkrows - 1, ListView1.Items.Count - 1)
Dim text As String = ListView1.Items(row).Text
Dim found As Boolean
    For Each item2 As ListViewItem In ListView2.Items
        If text.Contains(item2.Text) Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
If found Then numFound += 1
Next
If numFound > 0 Then MessageBox.Show("At least one of the first " & checkrows.ToString & " rows         in ListView1 matches a row in ListView2")
If numFound = checkrows Then MessageBox.Show("The first " & checkrows.ToString & " rows in ListView1 match a row in ListView2")
```

Comment: Getting an error on Exit Loop maybe I can use Exit For?

Comment: Yes try that ... i think my code maybe slightly wrong there. didnt try to run it. This is to just show you what i meant. - i edited the answer.

Comment: Hmmm.. Still checks the whole list instead of the top 3 :/

Comment: debug it ... put a break point on it and step through code and look at the numbers... maybe a logic issue? > or < ?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by that... :) but it works just like the code i have, tried modifying it a little bit but doesn't work that way either.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thanks AltF4 but yours didn't really work out for me. Ty for putting your time into this anyway <3

```
Dim checkrows As Integer = 3
Dim numFound As Integer
    For row As Integer = 0 To Math.Min(checkrows - 1, ListView1.Items.Count - 1)
Dim text As String = ListView1.Items(row).Text
Dim found As Boolean
    For Each item2 As ListViewItem In ListView2.Items
        If text.Contains(item2.Text) Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
If found Then numFound += 1
Next
If numFound > 0 Then MessageBox.Show("At least one of the first " & checkrows.ToString & " rows         in ListView1 matches a row in ListView2")
If numFound = checkrows Then MessageBox.Show("The first " & checkrows.ToString & " rows in ListView1 match a row in ListView2")
```

Comment: This is practically my solution except with the code corrected - The point was the concept of how that can be achieved - as i said the code may not be exactly correct - So i have now replaced with your code. Please award my answer